# how can I flatten an enum to a special case when the explicit cases don't match

Tags: rust, serde

I'd like it so when the case is unknown, it will be associated with the last case

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Action {
    Action1,
    Action2,
    Action3,
    Other(String), // when not known it should be here
}
```

I've tried using the directive

`#[serde(untagged)]`

but then it doesn't serialize properly

```
let b = Action::Action1;
let s = serde_json::to_string(&b);
let ss = s.unwrap();
println!("ss {:#?}", &ss);
let val = serde_json::to_value(b);
println!("ss {:#?}", &val);
```

results in

```
ss "null"
ss Ok(
    Null,
)
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf1e188ceb3ff65d7c4a22075dd3bbb2)

Comment: I think you need to do a custom implementation, I don't think there is a building way to do that in serde

Comment: The only thing close is https://serde.rs/variant-attrs.html#other

Comment: I tried that but it does't compile when the case is `Other(String)` , will compile if it is `Other` (without the associated value)

Comment: error: #[serde(other)] must be on a unit variant

Comment: I didn't say it will do what you want I say it was the closest thing

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options that build off each other.

First use `From` to turn this into a string every time you serialize and then `From` to turn it back into your own type. This requires you to convert every time you serialize and deserialize but will accomplish your goal.

If you want to make the API a little cleaner at the cost of doing more work you can implement serialize and deserialize yourself. Here are some references on how to do that:

1. [Custom Serialization](https://serde.rs/custom-serialization.html)
2. [Implementing Serialize](https://serde.rs/impl-serialize.html)
3. [Implementing Deserialize](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html)

As a second option you can offload the custom serialization and deserialization if your willing to add another dependency of [serde_with](https://crates.io/crates/serde_with).

According to its docs:

> De/Serializing a type using the Display and FromStr traits, e.g., for u8, url::Url, or mime::Mime. Check DisplayFromStr or serde_with::rust::display_fromstr for details.